# How to enable cooperation of MS DTC on computers that are in domain and computers not running in a Windows domain?

Tags: msdtc

My application that runs on machine in domain uses TransactionScope (that relies on MS DTC). SQL Server runs on machine not included in domain. How to enable cooperation of MS DTC on computers that are in domain and computers not running in a Windows domain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[MSDN](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755250(v=ws.10).aspx)

> When Microsoft Distributed Transaction Coordinator (MS DTC) computers are not running in a Windows domain, distributed transactions fail by default because the remote procedure call (RPC) security that MS DTC uses cannot be used in this environment. The same condition applies to MS DTC computers that are in untrusted domains. In Windows Server 2003 and Windows Server 2008, RPC security is not turned off. Therefore, distributed transactions fail in a workgroup environment or in untrusted domains

- Open dcomcnfg
- In the Distributed Transaction Coordinator folder under My Computer, right-click Local DTC, and then click Properties
- on Security tab select the Network DTC Access check box, and then select No Authentication Required